# I can't get cython to work due to even though I have a C++ compiler.

Tags: python-2.7, cython, anaconda

I am using python 2.7.10 (64bit) with anaconda 2.4.0 (64bit) and cython 0.23.4, with the latest updates for setuptools, pip, and wheel. I have also downloaded and installed a C compiler from this link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266.

I then wrote the following hi.pyx file:

```
    print "Hello"
```

And the following setup.py file

```
    from distutils.core import setup
    from Cython.Build import cythonize

    setup(
      name = 'Hello world app',
      ext_modules = cythonize("hi.pyx"),
    )
```

The vcvarsall.bat file is located here:
C:\Users\c3126_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual_C++_for_Python\9.0
so I have added this to the path system variable.

I ran the following command in the Anaconda prompt

```
    cython -2 hi.pyx
```

And this produced the file hi.c
I then ran the command

```
    python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

which gave the following error:
    Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

so I ran the following commands:

```
    SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
    SET MSSKdK=1
```

And then ran this command again:

```
    python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

which gave the error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory.
Now I don't know what else to do. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not using anaconda.
To compile the pyx file I open the CMD shell from the SDK and there I enter (compiling for x64):

```
set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
setenv /x64 /release
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```